# Swift 1.2 Documentation Changes (Markdown Support)

Tags: ios, swift

I just upgraded to Xcode 6.3 and it has the Swift 1.2 support.  I was loading quick documentation in a swift file for the `description` variable as part of the `Printable` protocol.

I noticed that the documentation has a nice little inline code block.  I'm as of yet unsure if this was there in the previous version of swift and whether it is "special" or they've added more support for features for inline documentation.

Anybody aware of how to do this for my own quick-help?

[image]

I believe Obj-c documentation has much more "features" and perhaps as this is part of an Objc protocol thats why the documentation is "fancy"

Update the following:

```
/** 

Test Protocol Definition

    Code Block

**BOLD**


*/
```

Renders as:

[image]

Comment: I remember seeing somewhere that the documentation blocks support basic markdown now. I can't seem to find a link though.

Comment: Looks like some markdown is working... cool!

Comment: [Thus answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27766320/608157) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for offtopic: how did you make that tooltip so fancy transparent? ;)

Comment: Which tooltip?  The Xcode tooltip is a 3 finger tap which launches quick-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some "sleuthing" the closest I could come to for an answer was at: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=24

*Stylized text is easy to add to your playground by adding special markup to your comments based on the familiar Markdown syntax. Some available styles are headings, bold, italic, lists, bullets, and links to external or bundled resources.*

Although the blog post is specifically talking about the new **Playgrounds** it would appear they have used the same renderer in Xcode to generate quick-doc/quick-help (which is great).

What I've gathered is that the following is supported

- Code block :  Indent some number of spaces.  (Behavior seems a little temperamental because sometimes it seems just 1 space will work)
- Bold Text: **
- Italic Text: *

The following does not seem to work:

- Any sort of URL Linking
- Underline

The Playground markdown document is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Playground_Ref/Chapters/MarkupReference.html however as seen above not everything is applicable to inline documentation of code

Comment: Does anyone know if the Swift MarkUp comes with a tool to read the markdown in the implementation files and spit out html similar to what Apple had for their version of reStructuredText?

Comment: Google jazzy doc by realm