# How can I properly document a method with a completion handler in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, documentation

I'm documenting the code for my company's iOS application, and now I've moved on to methods that have a completion handler. Is there a specific method for documenting completion handlers, or should I just put it as part of the parameters?

for example:

```
/**
Description
- Parameters:
     - parameter1: description
     - parameter2: description
     - completion: description
*/
```

Is this the right way or is there another better way? Or maybe it should be in the "Returns" part of the documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
Sends an API request to 4sq for venues around a given location with an optional text search

:param: location    A CLLocation for the user's current location
:param: query       An optional search query
:param: completion  A closure which is called with venues, an array of FoursquareVenue objects

:returns: No return value
*/
func requestVenues(location: CLLocation, query: String?, completion: (venues: [FoursquareVenue]?) -> Void) { … }
```

taken from https://thatthinginswift.com/documentation-and-quick-help/

Answer (score 17):

*Since the previous accepted answer failed to compile under Swift 3 (Function types cannot have argument label.) I would like to add an updated answer:*

```
/**
Find User ID from Request
- Parameter from: The request containing relevant information.
- Parameter completionHandler: The callback called after retrieval.
- Parameter userId: The retrieved user id.
*/
static func extractUserId(from: RouterRequest, completionHandler: (_ userId: String) -> Void)
```

## Result

[image]
[image]

Looks good enough for me!

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it's currently (as of jan 2017) not directly supported in the Swift comment syntax. There is an issue open, and I encourage you to vote on it/fix it :) https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-874

---

However, the block type could be defined separately:

```
/**
 - parameters:
    - error: See RequestError
    - image: Available if error is nil
*/
typealias RequestHandler = (_ error:RequestError?, _ image:UIImage?)->()

/** Requests a remote UIImage
 - parameter url: where to look for the image
 - parameter callback: invoked when request failed or completed
*/
func requstFrom(url: URL, callback:RequestHandler) { /* ... */ }
```

...which would allow for a somewhat not-terrible looking documentation:
[image: trivial documentation example]
[image: trivial documentation example 2]

Answer (score 1):

Try the [VVDocumenter-Xcode](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) tool, which will extract your parameters and return into documents automatically, like javadoc style.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a a `typealias` for your completion handler. You can reuse it better and your code is clearer for the user.

On the other hand you can create a complete documentation about this like you used to.

`typealias closureType = (parameterTypes) -> (returnType)`