# Is it possible to add images to the comments of code in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, comments

Basically, I am writing a program that involves a lot of trig and mathematical manipulations that will later on have to be reviewed. Explaining what is happening in this section of the code with words is hard. I was wondering if it's possible to add a diagram in the comments of the code to help ease an explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047991/does-swift-have-documentation-comments-or-tools).

Comment: And see [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH17-SW1) to the official Apple documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you ship your code as an Xcode playground, you can have your comments styled as rich text with Markdown formatting, and add hyperlinks and images. (A playground is a file package — a folder that looks like a single file — so you can put your image files inside and reference them from the playground source, and they'll render inline with the rest of your markup.)

As noted in comments, Apple has [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH17-SW1) explaining the comment formatting for images and other markup.