# How to go about adding a link/reference to another method in documentation Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, documentation

I am adding some description to my method in class. This is how I achieved this:

[image]

And it looks like this upon clicking...

[image]

How can I make the underlined method clickable? I want it to be referenced so that when a user clicks on it, they are directed to a particular web page for documentation.

Is it even possible? 
Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Swift have documentation comments or tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047991/does-swift-have-documentation-comments-or-tools)

Comment: Try to use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047991/does-swift-have-documentation-comments-or-tools

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk Thank you so much! That solved my problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047991/does-swift-have-documentation-comments-or-tools) solved my problem

Particularly, this is how I went about it

[image]

Thanks to Oleg for the link

Comment: using (as the image suggests) `https://www,myLink` doesn't work for me. I would have been very surprised if it did have worked, but I checked it anyhow. I'm using Xcode 9.4

Comment: I really tried to find solution for this problem. Unfortunately, it seems the JavaDoc style links are still unsupported even in Xcode 10. Sad...

Answer (score 121):

### New in Xcode 13

Using the new DocC tool in Xcode, you can now reference other methods by using a double backtick.

If the type, property, or method you are referencing is not a "sibling" of the one you are documenting, you can refer to it by qualifying the reference.

```swift
struct House {
    /// The rooms in the house.
    var rooms: [Room]

    /// The maximum size of the household.
    ///
    /// This is calculated by summing the ``Room/occupancyLimit`` of this 
    /// house's ``rooms``.
    var maximumHouseholdSize: ...
}

struct Room {
    /// The maximum number of occupants allowed in the room.
    var occupancyLimit: ...
}
```

Here, the documentation comment for `House.maximumHouseholdSize` references `House.rooms` with:

```
``rooms``
```

because `rooms` is a sibling of `maximumHouseholdSize`.

It also references `Room.occupancyLimit` with:

```
``Room/occupancyLimit``
```

because `occupancyLimit` is not nested in the same type, but rather under the `Room` type.

---

### Prior to Xcode 13

You can link to another method by tagging it with `/// - Tag:` and referring to it by `Tag` using the `x-source-tag://[Tag]` scheme like so:

```swift
/// - Tag: someMethod
func someMethod() {
   ...
}

/// Make sure to call [someMethod](x-source-tag://someMethod) at some point when overriding.
func otherMethod() {
   ...
}
```

Clicking on the `someMethod` link in the Quick Help pop-over will take you to the method and flash-highlight it in yellow.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read the question and realized that the OP was asking about linking to web pages. This is an answer to the title of the question, though, so I'm leaving it in place.

Comment: Does not seem to work in Playgrounds with Xcode 10.2.1

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING!! I've been looking for this for 3 years now! Works in Xcode 11.5 as well. Thank you!

Comment: This works well, but overrides any other comments that you may have below it.

Comment: about "x-source-tag", what if I have 2 files, each have a tag of the same name. Can Xcode figure out which one to link to?

Comment: How to link to a particular line number?

Answer (score -4):

Use this

```
 /**
     *  <#Description#>
     *
     *  @link UILabel <#UILabel description#>
     *
     *  @return <#return value description#>
     */
```

Or you can try vvDocumenter for giving comments

Comment: I don't think that works. I just tried this syntax:

`<#ClassName methodName#>`

and I think that's the syntax for autocomplete suggestion placeholders.