# Xcode Markup Link Reference Within Same File

Tags: swift, xcode, reference, markup

I want to make a link reference within the same file in Swift kind of like the way you can in JavaDoc, but I can't seem to find documentation describing how to do this. You can only reference external URLS. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
class myClass : UIView {

    /// The label that displays the scale of this view
    /// - seealso: [showScaleView](showScaleView())
    private lazy var scaleView: UIView = UIView()

    /// Shows the scale view
    /// - seealso: [scaleView](scaleView)
    private func showScaleView() {
       ...
    }

}
```

Comment: This question will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321880/how-to-go-about-adding-a-link-reference-to-another-method-in-documentation-xcode

Comment: @RodrigodeSantiago How is that supposed to help? That question is only about referencing external web pages. OP specifically asked about linking to a method within the same file.

Comment: No resolution for problem so far ?

Comment: @AntonMalmygin not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This known issue in Xcode since Jan 2018...  :(

Here is radar: https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/19263

Comment: I sure hope they will address this requirement soon