# Add links to Swift classes in the quick help documentation comments?

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, comments

Assume I have two classes:

```
/**
  This class should be used together with [Foo]( ??? ).
*/
class Bar {
    func doNothing() {}
}

/**
  Description of what Foo does goes here.
*/
class Foo {
    func doNothing() {}
}
```

I want to create a link to Foo or Foo's quick help from Bar's quick help in Xcode. Is it even possible? If so, how?

The `[name](target)` syntax for links isn't up to snuff as far as I can tell by looking at [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Links.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH18-SW1) and [more Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/MarkupFunctionality.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH54-SW1).

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633899/1457385

Comment: A good thread for sure, but it doesn't address my question.

Comment: Did you find any solution to the above?

Comment: No. I gave up, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Seems like it. A pity, I'd love that :(

Comment: Has anyone been able to do this?

Comment: You can achieve this by using Tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321880/how-to-go-about-adding-a-link-reference-to-another-method-in-documentation-xcode/54564301#54564301

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift annotation "Tag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539020/swift-annotation-tag)

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this.  Apparently, if the text you enclose in backticks happens to be a class, it will be rendered as a hyperlink to the class.

Comment: I just tried this: `/** Example: "Bar()", another example: "doNothing()" */` - it only changed the font to a monospace one and didn't add a link. Edit: Stackoverflow changes the func names surrounded by backticks to code... To try it yourself, replace the four quotation marks with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

This is done using double backticks (``) around your symbols name.

This is documented in detail here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/formatting-your-documentation-content