# Swift annotation "Tag"

Tags: ios, swift, code-documentation

Since Objective-C I'm a fan of `#pragma MARK:` but recently I've seen `/// -Tag:` in Apple's source code. Also noteworthy, it's highlighted in white, while `MARK` isn't. `Tag` on the other side does not add any text to the Xcode 'outline' view.

Can anyone explain what the purpose of `Tag` is?

[image: Method annotated with 'Tag']

Comment: Which version of XCode?

Comment: Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)

Comment: Just a terminology note: the `#pragma MARK:` (or `// MARK:` in Swift) is a way to organize your code. You can search for marks in the *jump bar* at the top of Xcode (click on the class or struct name to see the symbols in your object). `/// - Tag:` is an item for *Quick Help* display - which allows you to document, or see documented, as in this case,  information regarding a specific symbol (function or variable). Though they both are forms of documentation, they have very different purposes and functionality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go about adding a link/reference to another method in documentation Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321880/how-to-go-about-adding-a-link-reference-to-another-method-in-documentation-xcode)

Comment: Sure, but that's the new stuff. Back in 2018, when there where dinosaurs, we didn't had such fanciness.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `- Tag:` annotation is used to locate specific places of your own code. You can include it as part of [symbols documentation in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Links.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH18-SW6). E.g. you may add a `Tag` marker in some Swift file next to a function:

```swift
/// - Tag: myFunction
func myFunction() {
  print("My function is called")
}
```

In another file you can refer to this exact place in the code as part of another Swift entity documentation:

```swift
/// Uses [myFunction](x-source-tag://myFunction) internally
func anotherFunction() {
  myFunction()
}
```

When using the Quick Help popover on `anotherFunction` in Xcode, you get an interactive reference (under **myFunction** text), which takes you to the file (and line) where the `/// - Tag: myFunction` is located:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find anything specific to the `Tag` documentation keyword. It appears to be a custom documentation keyword, though it doesn't appear in *Quick Help* as expected...

I'm guessing that it may just be a way to allow searching for related code... Maybe it'll come up as a new feature in the future - used to apply "tags" to specific symbols, as you would in Finder, say. That seems reasonable, given that the function referenced in the question is related to custom clustering (see [*Decluttering a Map with MapKit Annotation Clustering*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering)), and the documentation line says `/// - Tag: CustomCluster`.

---

When you write a function, you can document the details of that function in Swift using a version of "markdown". See the [*Markup Formatting Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/) and [*CommonMark*](http://commonmark.org) for examples.

This documentation appears in the *Quick Help* popover box, as shown in the question, and in the *Quick Help Inspector* - displayed in the right-hand panel when your cursor is in a symbol (function name, for example), and you click the question mark in a circle at the top of the inspector panel.

Many pre-defined keywords exist for this documentation, such as `- Parameters:`, `- Returns:`, and `- Throws:`. And, you can also use your own custom keywords. Usually the custom keywords appear in the *Quick Help* as well, but this `- Tag:` keyword doesn't seem to do anything (at least in Xcode 9.4.1).

Here's an example of how to use Swift Documentation Markup:

```
/// Errors associated with String processing.
enum StringError: Error {
    case cantCapitalizeAnEmptyString
}

/// Capitalizes a String item.
/// - Tag: I don't know what this is - it doesn't show in Quick Help.
/// - Parameter string: A String item to be capitalized.
/// - Throws `StringError.cantCapitalizeEmptyString` when provided String item is empty.
/// - Returns: The provided String item converted to all capital letters.
/// - Blah: A custom keyword I made up.
func capitalize(string: String) throws -> String {
    if string.isEmpty {
        throw StringError.cantCapitalizeAnEmptyString
    }
    return string.capitalized
}
```

Then, in the *Quick Help Inspector*, you'll see:

[image: Quick Help Inspector showing custom documentation]

Or, of course, option-clicking the function name will display the *Quick Help* popover:

[image: Quick Help Popover showing custom documentation]

As noted in the question, the `- Tag:` keyword doesn't display anything in either the *Quick Help Inspector* or the *Quick Help popover*.