# Is it possible to link to another function in Swift documentation?

Tags: swift, xcode

Say I have two functions that are documented like this:

```swift
/**
 Fetches something.

 - PostCondition: 'displaySomething()' is called by the presenter
*/
func fetchSomething() {
    interactor?.fetchSomething()
}

/**
 Displays something.

 - Parameter viewModel: A viewmodel containing the parsed data        
*/ 
func displaySomething(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    text = viewModel.text
}
```

Is there a way to make the reference to displaySomething() in the fetchSomething() documentation link to the actual function so that it is clickable in quick help? As far as I can tell it is currently only possible to link to web pages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635270/add-links-to-swift-classes-in-the-quick-help-documentation-comments :)

Comment: Seems to be not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift annotation "tag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539020/swift-annotation-tag)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!