# xcode: how to create method documentation automatically

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047991/does-swift-have-documentation-comments-or-tools) answer to document my classes in swift. My question is: is there a way to create the documentation of methods automatically inside xcode? I mean, just as you to in php strom when you just type /** + enter, or /// + enter in visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - in Xcode this is called Quick Help documentation.

You can automatically generate the documentation stub by putting your cursor inside the method or class name, and pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
/// Returns the sum of four values
///
///
/// - Parameters:
///     - a: Value 1
///     - b: Value 2
///     - c: Value 3
///     - d: Value 4
func calculate(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double, d: Double) -> Double {
    return a + b + c + d
}
```

Which will return:
[image]