# How to add lists in Xcode documentation markup?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add documentation to my code in Xcode. I've followed a couple of articles that suggest my markup should work with Xcode preview (https://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/ and https://sarunw.com/posts/swift-documentation/) but the bullet point list isn't displaying. Have I missed something obvious?

```swift
    /**
     Formats date components into a sensible representation given the other date components included.

     # Examples:

     * If two dates are in the same year, the common year will be returned.
     * If two dates are in the same month and year, the common months and year will be returned.
     * If two dates don't share any commonality, nil is returned.
     */
    func formattedString(for components: [DateComponents]) -> String? {
        getFormattedDateRange(for: components)
    }
```

But this is the preview I get at the call site:

[image: Image showing incomplete documentation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with lists, but *headings*. Notice that if you remove the heading `# Examples:`, or just the `#` character, the markdown is rendered as expected.

For some reason, Xcode ignores all the text after it encounters a heading of any kind in a documentation comment.

See this example from [this very old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28633899/5133585). It apparently worked back then!

```
/// Text like this appears in "Description".
///
/// Leave a blank line to separate further text into paragraphs.
///
/// You can use bulleted lists (use `-`, `+` or `*`):
///
/// - Text can be _emphasised_
/// - Or **strong**
///
/// Or numbered lists:
///
/// 7. The numbers you use make no difference
/// 0. The list will still be ordered, starting from 1
/// 5. But be sensible and just use 1, 2, 3 etc…
///
/// ---
///
/// More Stuff
/// ==========
///
/// Code
/// ----
///
/// Use backticks for inline `code()`. Indentations of 4 spaces or more will create a code block, handy for example usage:
///
///     // Create an integer, and do nothing with it
///     let myInt = 42
///     doNothing(myInt)
///
///     // Also notice that code blocks scroll horizontally instead of wrapping.
///
/// Links & Images
/// --------------
///
/// Include [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink), and even images:
///
/// ![Swift Logo](/Users/Stuart/Downloads/swift.png "The logo for the Swift programming language")
///
/// - note: That "Note:" is written in bold.
/// - requires: A basic understanding of Markdown.
/// - seealso: `Error`, for a description of the errors that can be thrown.
///
/// - parameters:
///   - int: A pointless `Int` parameter.
///   - bool: This `Bool` isn't used, but its default value is `false` anyway…
/// - throws: A `BadLuck` error, if you're unlucky.
/// - returns: Nothing useful.
public func doNothing(int: Int, bool: Bool = false) throws -> String {
    return "Totally contrived."
}
```

Xcode's "discussion" part stops before the first heading,

[image]

(Try deleting the headings and see what happens!)

The parameters and returns seem to be rendered fine though.

On the other hand, if I use a documentation generator like `jazzy` like the linked answer suggests, the headings and all the other text are rendered properly:

[image]

There is no Swift Logo because I didn't download one to my local machine :) Your documentation for `formattedString` function is also generated properly by `jazzy`, without needing to change anything.

As another alternative, AppCode generates documentation for both your `formattedString` function and the above example correctly too.

So I think this is a just a quirk/bug in Xcode. Documentation generators can still properly generate documentations from these comments.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response - really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is fixed part (removed #, and wrapping comment is only /** */, you don't need * at every line for comment itself, but it's a mark for list item)

```
 /**
  Formats date components into a sensible representation given the other date components included.

  Examples:
  * If two dates are in the same year, the common year will be returned.
  * If two dates are in the same month and year, the common months and year will be returned.
  * If two dates don't share any commonality, nil is returned.

  */
 func formattedString(for components: [DateComponents]) -> String? {
      getFormattedDateRange(for: components)
 }
```

[image]